# Direct2D drawing not working when returning from lock screen

Tags: windows, mfc, direct2d

I have an MFC application which is working correctly using Direct2D... except one things : when I lock my computer (Windows) while application is runing, the display is not refreshed anymore whn I unlock computer.

Note that the application is runing normally and just resizing the application make it work again.

Here's the main parts of my code :

into class View constructor

```
    // Enable D2D support for this window:
    EnableD2DSupport();
```

And the Draw part

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMyView::OnDraw2d(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CHwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;
    ASSERT_VALID(pRenderTarget);
    if (pRenderTarget == NULL)
        return -1;

    pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(m_rect, m_pLinearGradientBrush);
    ...
```

My application is based on this example, which doesn't contains either BeginDraw nor EndDraw : 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/MFC-Direct2D-Hello-World-9aa6ae00

Comment: Are you properly checking the return value for [ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371924.aspx)? If it returns `D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET` you will have to recreate your render target. Also make sure that you have a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message handler that triggers rendering/recreation as outlined at [Creating a Simple Direct2D Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was not calling EndDraw() at all. Now I added this call and as soon as I press CTRL-ALT-DEL I get a return code : 0x8899000c. I tried to call ReCreate() but this seems not to be the right way to resolve it.

    hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        pRenderTarget->ReCreate(m_hWnd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks IInspectable for the hint ! Here's the code that fixed it for me (at the end of CMyView::OnDraw2d).

```
...
hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  pRenderTarget->ReCreate(m_hWnd);
  delete m_pTraceRenderTarget;
  m_pTraceRenderTarget = NULL;
}
```

For normal case I guess the pRenderTarget->ReCreate(m_hWnd); call should be enough. But on my case it was not working because I was owning a second CompatibleRenderTarget. By releasing it, I force it to re-create later on my code :

```
if (m_pTraceRenderTarget == NULL)
{
    m_pTraceRenderTarget = new(CBitmapRenderTarget);
    pRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(*m_pTraceRenderTarget/*, CD2DSizeF((100.0), (100.0))*/);
}
```